# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable when trying to call method

Tags: python, object, tuples, typeerror, callable

Here is what I have going on so far:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import time

class Item():
    def __init__(self, name, description, base_value):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.ingredients = ingredients
        self.base_value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return format(self.name, self.description, self.ingredients, self.base_value)


class Metal(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, description, ingredients, base_value):
        self.smelt_time = smelt_time
        self.smelted = smelted
    def __str__(self):
        return format(self.name, self.description, self.ingredients, self.base_value, self.smelt_time, self.smelted)

class Bronze_Ingot(Metal):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Bronze Ingot",
        self.description = "A refined ingot of bronze."
        #self.ingredients = Tin_Ore(1)+Copper_Ore(1) <--- I will get these lines working later...
        self.base_value = 33
        self.smelt_time = 15
        self.smelted = ()            

class Fuel(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, description, ingredients, base_value):
        self.fuel_time = fuel_time
    def __str__(self):
        return format(self.name, self.description, self.ingredients, self.base_value, self.fuel_time)

class Cloth(Fuel):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Cloth",
        self.description = "A piece of cotton cloth."
        #self.ingredients = 2 Cotton <--- I will get these lines working later... 
        self.base_value = 2
        self.fuel_time = 5
```

But I am having great trouble with this function...

```
    def smelted(Fuel, Metal):
        if (Fuel.fuel_time - Metal.smelt_time) > 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Smelting", Metal.name, "..."
            time.sleep(Metal.smelt_time)
            print "Time to forge!"
```

The problem is more or less making it work. My friend and I have tried EVERYTHING that *we* can think of when running this function, but to no avail. Here is our most recent attempt:

```
from Smelting_Progress import *

x = Cloth()
y = Bronze_Ingot()

y.smelted(x,y)
```

After trying to run this, I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\WCS-HSSTUDENT\Desktop\Files\Project SAOffline\Coding\New Aincrad World\Items\NAI_Smelted.pyw", line 6, in <module>
    Metal.smelted(Fuel, Metal)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Unrelated: You forgot to call the parent constructors in your `__init__` functions.

Comment: Note that your traceback **doesn't match your code posted**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an instance attribute `smelted`; you set it in `Metal.__init__()`:

```
self.smelted = smelted
```

Your `Bronze_Ingot` subclass sets it to an empty tuple:

```
self.smelted = ()
```

You cannot have both a method and and a tuple use the same name. Rename one or the other.

If you meant to use your `smelted()` code as a *function*, then define it at the top level (same indentation as your classes), and call it as a function, not a method:

```
smelted(x, y)
```

(note, no `y.` in front).

Comment: @Clanton: You are calling `y.smelted`, which is the tuple. If `smelted(Fuel, Metal)` is meant to be a *function* then it is not a method of one of your classes and should not be called on an instance. Remove the `y.`.

Comment: Okay, this has now been done, yet I am receiving the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS-HSSTUDENT\Desktop\Files\Project SAOffline\Coding\New Aincrad World\Items\NAI_Smelted.pyw", line 6, in <module>
    smelted(x, y)
NameError: name 'smelted' is not defined

Comment: @Clanton: I did mention that you need to put `def smelted()` at the top level, not indented like methods on a class. :-)

Comment: Now I am free of syntax error, but I am not getting the desired phrases to print.

Comment: @Clanton: do a little debugging yourself; look at your `fuel_time` and `smelt_time` values.. do you think 5 - 15 will be greater than 0?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that stupid mistake. It's been a long day and clearly I am not thinking straight.